# hasOwnProperty() returns true for re-defined inherited method (toString()) however Mozilla docs says otherwise?

Tags: javascript, prototype-chain

Mozilla [hasOwnProperty doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) says

> Assignment to a property within an object will cause debuggers to show the property as belonging to the object instance; but this does not mean "hasOwnProperty" will be true. **When the property is inherited from a prototype, "hasOwnProperty()" is false, even if the object has its own copy.**

To test, I re-defined `Object.prototype.toString()` method in a new object (`o`) as shown below:

```
o = new Object();
o.toString = function(){
  console.log("ToString redefined");
}

Object.toString();

o.hasOwnProperty('toString');
```

AFAIU, `toString()` re-defined should return `false` because it's an inherited property but it returns `true`. Kindly explain?

Also, it would be great if someone could explain the following with an example:

> Assignment to a property within an object will cause debuggers to show the property as belonging to the object instance; but this does not mean "hasOwnProperty" will be true.

thanks
app

Comment: Somebody added the section you quoted recently: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty$compare?to=1246267&from=1226101 . I'm not sure what they are trying to explain with that, but as far as I am concerned, what they are saying is wrong.

Comment: I removed that section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty$compare?to=1251159&from=1248455

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance works via the prototype chain: when you try to access a property on an object, it will return the property of that object; if the object itself does not have that property, its prototype is checked for the same property, and so on until the property is found or the chain ends.

So:

```
let o = {};
o.toString();
```

This finds the property `toString` *on the prototype* of `o`.

```
o.toString = function () {};
o.toString();
```

Now there's no need to traverse the prototype chain, since `o` itself has a `toString` property (which you just assigned directly to it). Now it *does* have an *own property* `toString`.